# Phonegap Geolocation Accuracy is always equal to 2000 meters

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

For some reason I am getting 2000 meters accuracy when requesting the position.coords.accuracy parameter?

I am developing on iOS currently.

Here is my code:

var locationOptions = {
     enableHighAccuracy: true
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, locationOptions);

function onSuccess(position) {

```
 alert(position.coords.latitude + "\n" + position.coords.longitude);
 alert("Accuracy: " + position.cords.accuracy);
```

}

Unsure as to why this is.... I have looked at other resources and they seem to be getting below 50 meters even below 10!

Kind Regards,
Jacques

Comment: not very sure but just for a hint, have you enabled GPS on your phone?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have allowed location access 'While using the App' on my iPhone settings